# Grad Function Directional Derivative

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, classical-mechanics

Let $h(x, y)$ be some function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$ which outputs height of a hill at a given point $(x, y)$. At a given moment, I am travelling up the hill with velocity $\mathbf{v}$ at angle $\theta$ to $\nabla h$. How do I prove that the rate at which my height is increasing is $\mathbf{v} \cdot \nabla h$?

My progress:

I know that for some 2D vector $\mathbf{a}$, the expression $\mathbf{a} \cdot \nabla h$ will give me the slope of hill in direction of $\mathbf{a}$. So if $\mathbf{\hat{v}}$ is the unit vector in direction of $\mathbf{v}$, then $\mathbf{\hat{v}} \cdot \nabla h$ will give me the slope of hill in the direction of the velocity. Since $\mathbf{v} \cdot \nabla h = (\left|\mathbf{v}\right|)(\mathbf{\hat{v}} \cdot \nabla h)$, the equation is essentially saying that the rate at which my height is increasing is speed multiplied by my slope. But this equation is clearly incorrect. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write up the derivatives explicitly, you may read
$$ \mathbf{v} \cdot \nabla h =  \nabla h \cdot \mathbf{v} = \frac{\partial h}{\partial x} \frac{\operatorname{d} x}{\operatorname{d} t} + \frac{\partial h}{\partial y} \frac{\operatorname{d} y}{\operatorname{d} t},$$
which is exactly the rate of change $ \frac{\operatorname{d} h}{\operatorname{d} t}$ by chain rule.

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering what the flaw is in my reasoning though

Comment: In fact, your thinking is correct. Physically, the rate of change of my height should depend on two factors: 1. The slope of the hill, which governs how much height is gained provided that the distance travelled is the same, and 2. The speed of me, which governs how much height is gained provided that the slope is the same. So it is no surprise that the rate is the product of the two.